# Objective-C immutable object copyWithZone: ARC-compatible realization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, copy, automatic-ref-counting

As I assumed, this should work's fine for immutable object under ARC:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
```

But if I need deep copy, I should write something like this:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Immutable *copy = [[Immutable alloc] initWithStr:str];
    return copy;
}
```

So, If I assumed right, ARC would understand situation (1) and (2) and make right decision about "+1" for references.

Am I right ?

Comment: I think ARC basically treat every returning objects are autoreleased with exceptions of `alloc~` and `copy~`. 

I treat all returning objects under ARC are just `-retain`ed and `-autorelease`d semantically. And just adds one more `-retain` for alloc and copy cases. As a result, one retain and one autorelease can be eliminated, and only one retain will be survive...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems I'm right: I can't find any concrete documentation on topic, but I create separate test project with ARC turned off, then choose migrate to ARC. Here is code without ARC:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self retain];
}
```

This is what I got after migration:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
```

It's a magic how ARC works sometimes, but seems we should just believe it will doing it's job well. :-)

Comment: A copy should return a different object (a different pointer). So your solution may lead to problems...

Comment: @Macmade if the object is immutable, returning a retained pointer to the same object is acceptable. NSString, NSDate, etc. all do this.

Comment: Sure, it's acceptable. But it's important to be aware of this, especially if you deal with pointer comparison for some tasks. : )

Comment: @Macmade Pointer equality doesn't mean object equality. And it's responsibility of code-user, not writer.

Answer (score 4):

Automatic reference counting, [as stated in the specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), obeys standard Cocoa naming practices. This means that methods with the prefixes `init`, `copy`, and `new` are assumed to return objects that the caller owns (+1 reference count). Therefore, if you return an object from one of those methods, ARC automatically handles it this way since you no longer can explicitly retain it.

The one problematic case around this that Apple has pointed out would be a third-party framework using manually reference counted code where the authors did not follow standard naming conventions. An example they gave was a method returning an autoreleased string called `copyRightString`. This will be overreleased on ARC, because it will assume that a +1 reference counted object is returned from such a method.

You can force ARC to treat this method in a special manner using a modifier like the following:

```
-(NSString*) copyRightString NS_RETURNS_NON_RETAINED;
```

Mugunth Kumar has a little more detail on this in [his ARC migration writeup](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/).

Comment: It's `+alloc`, `+copy`, and `+new`. `-init` does not change the object's retain count.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan - Right, but they do appear to look for the `-init` prefix. From the above-linked specification: "The most common scenario this models is the retained return from init, alloc, new, and copy methods, but there are other cases in the frameworks." This is likely in combination with `-alloc`, but I've tripped up the static analyzer in the past with something I accidentally prefixed with `-init` by itself.

Comment: `-init` returns an object that must be released because it is only ever called immediately after `+alloc`. The actual retain is (on paper) done in `+alloc`, `-init` just "forwards" it.